Hide helper columns while preserving conditional formatting which is based on them
In SharePoint/Teams Lists I am performing some conditional formatting based on "End date" column, where depending on how many days have passed after end date will today I would do different formatting. For this I use couple of helper columns with 'Calculated (calculation based on other columns)' and values like =[Test end date] + 4.
Long story short I would like to hide these helper column in my view, however as soon as I do that that the column formula which depends on these helper columns for conditional formatting does not work anymore. Is there a way to actually hide them while preserving this, or there is nothing I can do?

Based on your description, I understand you want to apply JSON formatting based on a hide column in the list view. Is it right?
We can construct a JSON object that describes the elements that are displayed when a field is included in a list view. So, when a column is hided in the list view, the JSON formatting will be valid. It's by designed.

Add 42 days
42*24x60x60x1000
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "position": "relative"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "font-size": "36px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "=if([$ADateField], toLocaleDateString([$ADateField] + **42***24x60x60x1000), '')"
        }
      ]
    }


sorrry, what does this do? Is this a workaround to avoid using helper columns?

this code add 42 days to a date field, to hide your field on a condtion , here if the id equals 1037 "style": {
"position": "relative",
"display": "=IF([$Id] = 1037, 'none', 'block')"
},
